# Guzzle exception on hitting tokbox api although server is configured with ssl-certificate

Tags: ssl, tokbox

Trying to hit an API from tokbox and facing the following error despite of the server is already configured with ssl:

```
{
    "status": false,
    "error": {
        "classname": "Guzzle\\Http\\Exception\\ClientErrorResponseException",
        "message": "Client error response\n[status code] 403\n[reason phrase] Forbidden\n[url] https://api.opentok.com/session/create"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tokbox developer here

Are you using the correct authentication? Please check [1], in the "authentication" section

[1] https://tokbox.com/developer/rest/